# Trace minimization subject to constraints

Tags: matrices, optimization, matrix-calculus, constraint-programming, constraints

I have seen in an article that

$ \min_{\mathbf{K}} \hspace{0.2cm} tr[\mathbf{K} \Sigma \mathbf{K}^T]$
s.t. $ \mathbf{KH} = \mathbf{I} $

where $\mathbf{H}$ is of full column rank yields,

$\tilde{\mathbf{K} } = (\mathbf{H}^T\Sigma^{-1}\mathbf{H})^{-1}\mathbf{H}^T\Sigma^{-1}$.

Does anyone aware of some theorem related to this result.

Comment: Does $\Sigma$ have any special characteristics other than being invertible?

Comment: Not exactly. For simplicity you can assume its mean is zero. But don't think it is useful.

Comment: How do you know it has a solution?

Comment: It is one of the results used in a thesis. I think the above solution is correct. But couldn't find a reference for that. The thesis also not giving the mathematical proof. So it must be in somewhere.

Comment: $\Sigma $ should be positive semidefinite. Otherwise, the problem can be unbounded.

Comment: Yes. It is positive definite. Sorry I could not mention about it. Any suggestions for a reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let $L=(\sqrt{\Sigma})^{-1}H$ the minimization problem becomes
$$
\min_{K:K\sqrt{\Sigma}\cdot L=I}{\rm tr}((K\sqrt{\Sigma})(K\sqrt{\Sigma})^T)
=\min_{S:SL=I}\,{\rm tr}(SS^T)
=\min_{S:SL=I}\,\Vert S\Vert^2_{HS}
$$
Where $\Vert\cdot\Vert_{HS}$ is the Hilbert-Schmidt norm. This minimization problem is well-known, and its solution goes back to Penrose:"*[On best approximate solutions of linear matrix equations](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0305004100030929)*".
The minimum is attained  at a unique $S$ which is the pseudo-inverse of $L$. In our case : $S^{+}=(L^TL)^{-1}L^T$ because $L$ has full rank. Rolling back we see that the solution of the original minimization problem is given by
$\tilde K=(H^T\Sigma^{-1}H)^{-1}H^T\Sigma^{-1}$.